# curl command's wget get stuck with no response

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to fire a curl command on Ubuntu 14.04

```
curl -v https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -P chefdk -c stable -v 0.18.30
```

and this get stuck at

```
Getting information for chefdk stable 0.18.30 for ubuntu...
downloading https://omnitruck.chef.io/stable/chefdk/metadata?v=0.18.30&p=ubuntu&pv=14.04&m=x86_64
  to file /tmp/install.sh.2027/metadata.txt
trying wget...
```

It does not move ahead and no logs to debug. What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think your command has some errors.

```
curl -v
# this prints verbose messages you don't want to pipe
```

> ```
> < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> < Cache-Control: max-age=300, public
> ...
> ```

just download the shell script with

```
curl https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh -o install.sh
```

the run the command with the downloaded file.

**Update:**

To run `install.sh` you need to add the executable flag:

```
chmod +x ./install.sh
```

Comment: ./install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -P chefdk -c stable -v 0.18.30
bash: line 1: ubuntu: command not found
bash: line 2: Getting: command not found
bash: line 3: downloading: command not found
bash: line 4: to: command not found
bash: line 5: trying: command not found

Comment: updated my anwser

Comment: what about `sudo bash -s -- -P chefdk -c stable -v 0.18.30`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, but the install.sh usage is `usage: install.sh [-P project] [-c release_channel] [-v version] [-f filename | -d download_dir]`

Comment: so maybe it's just `./install.sh -c stable -v 0.18.30`

Comment: yeah tried `./install.sh -P chefdk -c stable -v 0.18.30` but same issue its trying wget. I think there is some network issue on the VM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56718/discussion-between-michael-d-and-love2code).